# How to enable browserURL function when using `learnr`

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am using `learnr` to build up in-class slides held by shiny.io. The codes I would like to show includes some calling an external API. The file is smoothly compiled and uploaded to shiny.io. However, when I ran the codes through the shiny server, I got an error stating that

`Cannot visit /tmp/RtmplHHftl/ID_20180123212516_1458.html because the browseURL function is disabled.`

I searched online and found only one [relevant post from Rstudio connect](https://blog.rstudio.com/2017/10/24/rstudio-connect-v1-5-8/) stating that the problem can be solved by using functions like `shiny::tags$a` function without any instruction about where and how to insert such functions.